# How install GeoIp on php 7.0.5 in centos?

Tags: php, geoip, php-7

i have php 7.0.5.

i want use from geoip to example get country of domain or country of ip.

how install GeoIp on php 7.0.5 in centos?

if php 7 dont have geoip so how get country of domain or country of ip and .... ?

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to help. I just updated to php7 and I have a way that works

Hi,

••1•• First, download the GeoCityLite

```
cd __path_of_your_choice
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
gunzip GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
```

••2•• Follow the step to install GeoIP2 with php composer
https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php

in short -> in your terminal :

> cd (path you want to install geoip like ine /etc/...)

(assuming you know composer if not see https://getcomposer.org/)

> php composer.phar require geoip2/geoip2:~2.0

••3•• Than, in your php it looks like this :

```
require_once '____path_to_you_composer_intalled/vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$geo2 = new Reader('/___path_to_your_GeoLite_database___/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
$geoInfos = $geo2->city($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$constant_REQUEST_CITY = $geoInfos->city->name ;
```

I hope this is helpfull